# Persistent Store can't find migration policy class in heavy migration

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm getting this error:

```
2015-12-29 03:13:41.603 n-back project[21345:474175] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/Nathan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EC2C60E2-9FC8-40D7-B16F-15960AA6B42A/data/Containers/Data/Application/8F8132B0-76E9-491E-BA1B-27A5D78CE7D0/Documents/data.sqlite options:{
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (BTRPolicy)} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSUnderlyingException = "Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (BTRPolicy)";
}
2015-12-29 03:13:41.608 n-back project[21345:474175] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b14eef0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (BTRPolicy)}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.}, [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (BTRPolicy)}, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.]
```

It seems to me that it's having problems finding the class BTRPolicy. It exists in the file BTRPolicy with the name BTRPolicy. It's subclassed properly and referenced as "BTRPolicy" in the custom policy selection on the utilities pane. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody else has this problem and this matches your google search: I figured it out, for some reason custom policies need to be prefixed with the module name now.

Comment: Is it only for Swift or also for Objective-C?

Comment: Only for Swift.